# Credential to connect the Google Calendar API in Go

Tags: go, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I am converting a PHP application to access Google calendar to Go. I used   this [step by step](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/go) to get started.

All went smoothly, but when I run `quickstart.go`, I get the following error:

> Unable to parse client secret file to config: oauth2/google: missing
>   redirect URL in the client_credentials.json exit status 1

Content of the `client_secret.json` is:

```
{  
   "installed":{  
      "client_id":"***********content.com",
      "project_id":"*******",
      "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      "token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs"
   }
}
```

That `client_secret.json` file is located at the root of my GOPATH as instructed in the step by step

I already have a`OAuth 2.0 client ID` for my PHP app that works just fine in PHP. I just want to use that one in the a new Go application to access multiple user calendars, but when I download the json file attached to that ID, I am getting the error above. Maybe the `quickstart.go` is not meant for that usage.

Any hints?

Comment: first thought is the client secret json looks strange which type of credentials did you create?

Comment: It was created using the Google Developpers console if I remember.

Comment: Ok, I have created a new service account key. The json file attached to that key produce this error `Unable to parse client secret file to config: oauth2/google: no credentials found`.

Comment: There is your problem then that code is for Oauth2 not service accounts, create Oauth2 credentials and try again.

Comment: I already have a` OAuth 2.0 client ID` for my PHP app that works just fine in PHP. I just want to use that one for the a new Go application to access multiple user calendars, but when I download the json file attached to that ID, I am getting the error mentioned in my OP above. Maybe the `quickstart.go` is not meant for that usage. (copy of this comment in OP for reference)

Comment: you need an oauth2 json file not a service account json file they are two different things.

Comment: The existing Oauth2 json file that I try to use is apparently valid if I believe [this link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets). I have now to find out how to use it in Go.

Comment: you will need to add http ://localhost at redirect_uri on google console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create OAuth credentials at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials the dialog initially prompts you to "Configure your OAuth client" and you can choose between "Web application", "Desktop app", etc.

The `client.json` obtained for the generated OAuth credentials may not contain a "Return URL", depending on the type chosen initially.

For example, for "Web application" the `client.json` does not have a redirect URL:

```
{
  "web": {
    "client_id": "x.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "project_id": "x",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "x"
  }
}
```

While for a "Desktop app" it has:

```
{
  "installed": {
    "client_id": "x.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "project_id": "x",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "x",
    "redirect_uris": [
      "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
      "http://localhost"
    ]
  }
}
```

The Go oauth.google module always requires a return URI: https://github.com/golang/oauth2/blob/0f29369cfe4552d0e4bcddc57cc75f4d7e672a33/google/google.go#L61